# using ng-repeat-start to repeat multiple <td> element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

If you look at this plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/evBFK07EAoJAkHLZSV2g?p=preview , you'll see the use of `ng-repeat` in index.html.

```
<table ng-controller="GadgetIconsCtrl" >
  <tr ng-repeat="widget in widgetSubset"  >
    <td>
      <div class="image-clicked" ng-click="widgetClick($event, widget)" 
           ng-class="{clicked: widget.clicked}">
        <img ng-src="{{widget.initImage}}" 
             title="{{widget.title}}" width="64" height="64">{{widget.title}}
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's working fine, however, I'd like to implement `ng-repeat-start` somehow in order to display two unique `<td>` elements per `<tr>` .

What it's currently doing is displaying one  per  as follows. Please click RUN SNIPPET below to see the ouput:

```html
<table class="gadgetsTable">
  <tbody>
    <!-- ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->
    <tr ng-repeat="gadget in gadgets.subset" class="ng-scope">
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}" class="clicked">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/" title="Bar Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Bar Chart
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->
    <tr ng-repeat="gadget in gadgets.subset" class="ng-scope">
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/column_stacked.png" title="Column Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Column Chart
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->
    <tr ng-repeat="gadget in gadgets.subset" class="ng-scope">
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/column_line.png" title="Column Line Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Column Line Chart
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->
    <tr ng-repeat="gadget in gadgets.subset" class="ng-scope">
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/" title="Column 100% Stacked" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Column 100% Stacked
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the output to look more like this, with three  elements per :

```html
<table class="gadgetsTable">
  <tbody>
    <!-- ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->
    <tr ng-repeat="gadget in gadgets.subset" class="ng-scope">
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}" class="clicked">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/bar.png" title="Bar Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Bar Chart
      </td>
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/column_stacked.png" title="Column Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Column Chart
      </td>
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}" class="clicked">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/bar.png" title="Bar Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Bar Chart
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->

    <tr ng-repeat="gadget in gadgets.subset" class="ng-scope">
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}" class="clicked">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/bar.png" title="Bar Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Bar Chart
      </td>
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/column_stacked.png" title="Column Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Column Chart
      </td>
      <td class="ng-binding">
        <!-- set clicked css class when image is clicked : ng-class="{'image-border': gadget.initImage===widget.initImage}" -->
        <div ng-class="{clicked: gadget.clicked}" class="clicked">
          <img ng-click="gadgets.selectChart(gadget)" ng-src="images2/bar.png" title="Bar Chart" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10/">
        </div>
        Bar Chart
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: gadget in gadgets.subset -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this using `ng-repeat-start` ?

thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to get the data structure to be easier to bind into the view so you can get what you want with some nested ng-repeats.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qH2PdnoAPGZkJruahSWn?p=preview

```
    <tr ng-repeat="set in setOfSets">
      <td ng-repeat="widget in set">
        <div class="image-clicked" ng-click="widgetClick($event, widget)" ng-class="{clicked: widget.clicked}">
          <img ng-src="{{widget.initImage}}" title="{{widget.title}}" width="64" height="64" />
          {{widget.title}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

I used lodash to simplify redoing the grouping

```
  $scope.setOfSets = _.toArray(_.groupBy($scope.widgetSubset, function(item, index){
    return Math.floor(index/3)
  }))
```

Comment: wow, that's a great solution. Simple and sophisticated. I thought a nested repeat would work but I couldn't figure how to implement it.

Comment: so the `_.groupBy` is essentially returning an array of arrays - three sub-arrays, that is.

Comment: Yeah it returns an array of arrays but each sub-array has 3 elements basically whatever you return from that function is used to group elements together, so elements 0,1,2 will all be in "location" "0" since 0,1,2 divided by 3 and floored (remove remainder) is all 0 and 3,4,5 come out to 1, so you end up with 3 elements in each sub array and one outer object holding all of them, then the .toArray converts that object to an array.

Comment: WOW. That's all I can say. Appreciate it !

Comment: @bob believe me I'm pretty surprised too ;) typically though when fiddling with angular it's all about putting more focus on the model/data structures and then things flow easily from there.  Can always achieve things with directives/filters and stuff too but if you think of how the model can be bound into the view and build some helping data structures accordingly then things typically go well.